# Ensuring that Eigen uses AVX vectorization for a certain operation

Tags: c++, vectorization, eigen, simd, avx

I've written vectorized versions of some functions that are currently the bottleneck of an algorithm, using Eigen's facilities to do so.

I've also checked that AVX is enabled by making sure that `EIGEN_VECTORIZE_AVX` is defined after including Eigen.

However, it seems that my function never gets called with `Packet8f` (AVX),  if the data size is not a multiple of 8. Instead, it gets called with  `Packet4f` (SSE).

Here is a small repro: https://gist.github.com/bitonic/e89561cb21837b4dee8b5f49e1303919 . Here I define an operation using `Packet4f` and `Packet8f`, and then count how many times each gets called with an array of size 8 and 9. When the array is of size 8, the `Packet8f` version gets called once, as expected. When it's of size 9, the `Packet4f` version gets called twice instead, plus a single call to the non-vectorized version. I've tested this code on Eigen's current master `1d0c45122a5c4c5c1c4309f904120e551bacad02`.

I've dug a bit and I believe that packet selection is happening here: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/blob/1d0c45122a5c4c5c1c4309f904120e551bacad02/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h#L197 .

If I understand correctly, if the size of the data is not dynamic and not a multiple of 8 (that's the value of `unpacket_traits<Packet8f>::size`), the half-packet will be selected, which matches what the reproduction above shows.

If my understanding is correct, why is that the case? Shouldn't the full packet be selected, with the remaining elements working with the non-vectorized operation?

Could it be that that condition is wrong, and should be a >= comparison instead, e.g. something like

```
template<int Size, typename PacketType,
         bool Stop = Size==Dynamic || Size >= unpacket_traits<PacketType>::size || is_same<PacketType,typename unpacket_traits<PacketType>::half>::value>
struct find_best_packet_helper;
```

instead of

```
template<int Size, typename PacketType,
         bool Stop = Size==Dynamic || (Size%unpacket_traits<PacketType>::size)==0 || is_same<PacketType,typename unpacket_traits<PacketType>::half>::value>
struct find_best_packet_helper;
```

I've verified that with the fix above the problem goes away.

However I might be misunderstanding what is going on here, since I'm not very well versed in Eigen internals.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mre] (i.e., a snippet which compiles and which you can post here). Also, try to use the master branch of Eigen.

Comment: @chtz done, although it's still somewhat long since we need some boilerplate.

Comment: Related: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/issues/1714 -- there is definitely room for optimization for sizes which are not a multiple of the biggest packet size. But things are actually slightly more complicated to always get optimal results. Did you test if the test-suite still passes after your change? Could you submit a pull-request (ideally with an adapted packetmath unit test)?

Comment: I don't really see this as a possible optimization, but rather a mistake, since I don't see any upside in choosing half-packets that way (again, if I'm understanding what's going on correctly). I have opened a PR: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/merge_requests/46 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have confirmed that this is due to how Eigen selects the packet type, see https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/merge_requests/46 for a fix.